# Getting correct "this" in jQuery button callback

Tags: javascript, oop, this

I have a class:

```
function RustEditor() {

this.init = function() {

    var saveButton = this.container.find("button.saveButton");
    saveButton.click(function(){this.save();});

};
...
```

When I click the button, it complains that this.save is not a function. This is because "this" does not refer to the instance of RustEditor here, but to the button. What variable can I use inside that callback closure to point to the instance of RustEditor? I could use rust.editor (it's name in the global scope) but that's smelly code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Common practice is to enclose the `this` value like so:

```
 function RustEditor() {

 this.init = function() {
    var self = this;

    var saveButton = this.container.find("button.saveButton");
    saveButton.click(function(){self.save();});

 };
```

**Update with suggestion from tvanfosson**:
`this` gets rebound when the event handler is invoked and thus you need to capture the reference to the class at the time the object is created with a variable that will retain that reference in the closure.

Comment: It would improve your answer if you would explain why this needs to happen, to wit, _this_ gets rebound when the event handler is invoked and thus you need to capture the reference to the class at the time the object is created with a variable that will retain that reference in the closure.

Comment: @tvanfosson - Thanks for suggestion.  Hope you don't mind I quoted you verbatim.  You said it much better than I.

Answer (score 1):

Within RustEditor() you could first copy a reference to the button and use that.